# How to determine if there is really any delay in text input with company completion?

Tags: company-mode, text-editing

I use Company mode as completion. I like the gratification of instant completion popups. So I set the following setting:

```
(setq company-idle-delay 0.0)
```

So basically no delay before the pop-up appears.

However, I noticed someone said it would slow down the text input. When Googling around, I found no way to determine how this will delay the input of text. Any suggestion in order to determine the setting above will really delay the text input?

Answer (score 1):

It will slow down your typing as much as the backends you use are "slow" (use expensive processing inside Emacs, or even do that mostly outside Emacs but produce completions synchronously).

To test, try mashing your keyboard under different values of `company-idle-delay`, and see if there is a noticeable difference in how quickly the characters get inserted.

Comment: I can understand why it would cause any delay. The problem is that I don't notice any delay. So I'm asking here to have a way to measure this. I don't consider your reply as an answer, because mashing the keyboard is not a good way to measure it.

Comment: Try `(benchmark 1 '(your-favorite-backend 'candidates ""))`. That's not the only possible source of a delay, but it's the major one.

Comment: How could I get the output of that benchmark?

Comment: Check out that function's source.